# How do Refresh-Token (JWT) avoid to man-of-the middle attack?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, jwt, authorization

I recently implement JWT Auth with DotNet core Identity.

I know to reduce the number of authentication to get Access-Token (when it expires in a short time to aim more security) we use Refresh-Token to renew access-token instead of Re-authentication.

I think if a man-of-the-middle try to stole Refresh-Token to get new Access-Token and make a request (hijack token) how the system could find it and reject the request?

I mean is there a solution if JWT has stolen by someone to impersonate, server recognize it and reject it? (I know SSL could help but I am thinking about other ways. for example, encrypt JWT by time and Ip or .... ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using two way SSL between server and client, your concern is mostly moot.  The reason is that any man-in-the-middle, should he find a way to intercept, would not even know where the JWT begins and ends.  Instead, he would just be stuck with some encoded mess.  Hypothetically, if someone got a hold of a JWT, then yes he might be able to impersonate one of your users.  This would be no different than someone stealing a credit card and then masquerading as the owner.  But, due to SSL the likelihood of this happening is fairly small.

Comment: you mean it's not necessary to concern about hijack of JWT inside of client user?

Comment: Of course it is a concern, hence if you're talking about a website, you should never store the JWT to cookies or local storage, etc.  But the problem you are highlighting is not limited to JWT, it is a problem for _all_ data.

Comment: @Mohammad If you're really worried about a JWT getting hijacked, then follow the pattern used by the banks and other similar secure websites.  All of the tokens (auth and refresh) they give out are very short lived, a few minutes at most.  So, now even if someone hijacks a token, they would have to both obtain and use it very quickly, thereby reducing your risk even more (on top of the protection SSL already would be giving you).

Comment: Yeas, I think so, I found out with an SSL and reducing expiration of Access-Token and store JWT in a safe place in Browser we can decrease the risk of impersonating close to zero percent.